# how to split long string of text and add line break for each field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a long field that contains a string like this one:

1- SCRIPT 2- WHITE 3- EMB-1 4- * 5- * 6- Mrs. Petersen 7- loves 8- Mr. Petersen 9- * 10- * 11- * 12- 9990007878 13- Entered by customer: Flash App 14-  15- 71 16- 849b5629d0144e3c8293200910742e0d

I need to find a way to manipulate the string and have it formatted like :

1- SCRIPT
2- WHITE
3- EMB-1
 
4- *
 
5- *
 
6- Mrs. Petersen 
7- loves 
8- Mr. Petersen 
9- * 
10- * 
11- * 
12- 9990007878 
13- Entered by customer: Flash App 
14-  
15- 71 
16- 849b5629d0144e3c8293200910742e0d

the character that indicates the beginning of a new field is the number + '-' sequence I think.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the input? For example, can hyphens (-) show up in the input, other than in the record separator?

Comment: Are the numbers always going to be 1 to 16 or will this vary?

Comment: yes there could be hyphens like: 1- sign 1 - test line 1 2- sign 1 - test line 2 3- sign 1 - test line 3 4- sign 1 - test line 4 5- sign 1 - test line 5 6- PHONE: 1111111111 
But the record separator always will be "number - space" So far the higher it goes is 16, but that may change in the future. - Many thanks

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two options depending on if you need to preserve the prefix numbers you have two options. For both, I'm using regular expressions to help detect the boundaries of each field.

Here's the base regex:

```
\d+-\s
```

The regex looks for one or more digits (0-9), a hyphen, and then a space. This matches the pattern you provided.

```
0- Test   -- MATCH
1 - Test  -- No Match, space between the integer and hyphen.
9999-ABC  -- No Match, there is not a space between the hyphen and the value.
```

**Option 1**

This removes the prefix from the string.

```
Dim str As String = "1- SCRIPT 2- WHITE 3- EMB-1 4- * 5- * 6- Mrs. Petersen 7- loves 8- Mr. Petersen 9- * 10- * 11- * 12- 9990007878 13- Entered by customer: Flash App 14- 15- 71 16- 849b5629d0144e3c8293200910742e0d"

Dim items = Regex.Split(str, "\d+-\s", RegexOptions.None, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
```

**Option 2**
This preserves the prefix, and places the values into groups for easy access.

The regex on this method is slightly more complex by using negative look behinds. This makes it so we can determine if the value we're capturing would be part of the field value.

**EDIT** I changed this option to use the StringBuilder to rebuild the string with a delimited character. This is from the comment below.

```
Dim str As String = "1- SCRIPT 2- WHITE 3- EMB-1 4- * 5- * 6- Mrs. Petersen 7- loves 8- Mr. Petersen 9- * 10- * 11- * 12- 9990007878 13- Entered by customer: Flash App 14- 15- 71 16- 849b5629d0144e3c8293200910742e0d"

Dim matches = Regex.Matches(str, "(?<fieldNumber>\d+)-\s(?<fieldValue>(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)",   RegexOptions.None, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each match As Match In matches
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", match.Value)
    Dim matchedString = match.Value
    Dim fieldNumber = match.Groups("fieldNumber").Value
    Dim fieldValue = match.Groups("fieldValue").Value
Next

Dim entireString = sb.ToString()
```

**EDIT**

From your comment it sounds like you're just wanting to add a line break in between the fields. Here's an easy way to do that.

```
Dim ret = Regex.Replace(str, "(\d+-\s(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)", "$1\n", RegexOptions.None).Trim()
```

**RESPONSE***
(Just to be clear, this section is from the OP)

I added your code this way:

```
DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litNote"), Literal).Text = Regex.Replace(product.Note, "(\d+-\s(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)", "$1\n", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

When I run the page this is what I see (using a slightly different string):

1- sign 1 - test line 1\n 2- sign 1 - test line 2\n 3- sign 1 - test line 3\n 4- sign 1 - test line 4\n 5- sign 1 - test line 5\n 6- PHONE: 1111111111\n 7- Entered by customer\n 8- COMMENTS: this is test for sign 1\n 9- 5 LINE SIGN, STYLE: 98\n 10- SKU: 10140, QTY: 1\n 11- ee69ef2aff024a458488de10f498ac10\n

EDIT

I think I need to replace: "$1\n"

With: "$1<br />"

**Edit TO RESPONSE**

You are correct, depending on the place you're returning the output you may need a `<br/>` instead of the `\n`. I wasn't sure if you were using a `<pre>` tag or not. So I just made an assumption.

You also mentioned you'd like an explanation of the regex:

```
(\d+               -- look for one or more digits (0-9)
-                  -- look for a hyphen
\s                 -- look for a space
(?:                -- start a non-capturing group
  (?!\d+-\s).      -- do a negative look behind to see if we're inside of the delimited portion 
)*                 -- capture zero or more characters that satisfy the negative look behind (this and the negative look behind is the magic. It's what stops the match so that the next field can start)  
)
```

If you're not familiar with regexes, then I'd suggest reading up on the basics so that all this makes sense.

A good reference website 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Here's the portion about the look behind that is probably the confusing part in the regex:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

---

Hi Nathan

This is how i am implementing your option #2, so far

```
        Dim str As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim fieldNumber As String
        Dim fieldValue As String            
        str = product.Note
        Dim matches = Regex.Matches(str, "(?<fieldNumber>\d+)-\s(?<fieldValue>(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)", RegexOptions.None)
        For Each match As Match In matches
            fieldNumber = match.Groups("fieldNumber").Value
            fieldValue = match.Groups("fieldValue").Value
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}<br />", fieldValue)
        Next
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litNote"), Literal).Text = sb.ToString()
```

I am having difficulty understanding how to be able to manipulate the value of what goes into "fieldNumber"

---

Below is what I think you're trying to do. The styling you want to do Just [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) fieldNumber to an int then you can use it to determine what field you're on.

```
 Dim str As String
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder
 Dim fieldNumber As String
 Dim fieldValue As String            
 str = product.Note
 Dim matches = Regex.Matches(str, "(?<fieldNumber>\d+)-\s(?<fieldValue>(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)", RegexOptions.None)
 For Each match As Match In matches
    fieldNumber = match.Groups("fieldNumber").Value
    fieldValue = match.Groups("fieldValue").Value
    sb.AppendFormat("<p><label>{0}</label><span>{1}</span></p>", fieldNumber, fieldValue)
 Next
 DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litNote"), Literal).Text = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: When I try to use option 1 I get an error on:       Dim items = Regex.Split(Str, "\d+-\s", RegexOptions.None, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
- overload resolution failed because no accessible 'split' accepts this number of arguments

Comment: I don't know if I need to use an array, because right now the text field (prod.Note) is assigned to a multi line field on an aspx page like this: DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litNote"), Literal).Text = prod.Note

WI need to be able to first identify each field by the pattern and then add a line break, carriage return so that each field is put on the html page as a block.

Comment: The resolution failed problem is because I was using .Net 4.5, and I'm assuming you're on an older version. If you remove the new Timespan(0,0,30) parameter it will work for you.

Comment: will this work if i want to assigned the results to only one multi field on the page?

Comment: I added your code, with a little variation
Dim matches = Regex.Matches(product.Note, "(?<fieldNumber>\d+)-\s(?<fieldValue>(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)", RegexOptions.None)
For Each match As Match In matches
Dim entireMatchedString = match.Value
DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("litNote"), Literal).Text = entireMatchedString
Next

But I only see the last value printed on the page: 16- 849b5629d0144e3c8293200910742e0d

Comment: Yep, I probably wasn't clear on what entireMatchedString is. That variable stores a single match. So if you wanted to display all of them you would need to use something like a StringBuilder to add every "entireMatchedString" together. Then outside the for loop you would set your textbox with the StringBuilder. I'll edit the answer to show this. The other option would be to use the last version where I use Regex.Replace, it'll return back the entire string with a newline character between the matches.

Comment: Hi Nathan. I think I can be happy with the last version of your code recommendation. I was wondering if you could explain to me each of the parts that make up the regex?: "(\d+-\s(?:(?!\d+-\s).)*)"
Many thanks

Comment: See the edit, I gave a quick explanation. I'd strongly recommend reading some tutorials on Regexes if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I am not familiar with Regexes. I will read from the link you included. Thank you for your help, and the concise explanation.

Comment: Nathan. I have a question, I am thinking about using your code for separating the field number and the field value so that I can better style the string. I will have a maximum of 16 fields in a string. How can I identify in code, at which field I am and apply a custom text (label) instead that the number hyphen space? Soemthing like if field number is 1 then fieldnumber (text) is ItemNo.
Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I'm following, if you take a look at option 2 you should be able to put something together. Parse `fieldNumber` to an integer, and you can use it to help with the styling. Then you could place the formatting into the StringBuilder that's rebuilding the String by using the `fieldNumber` and `fieldValue` instead of the `match.Value`. The groups I have in the answer will strip off the `- ` from the output. If you need it you can place another capturing group around it and the fieldNumber to capture the number with `- `.

Comment: Nathan, thank you very much for your candid help. Your code has helped me to resolve the task I was working on. Best regards.